# x86 Intel Assembly and C++ - Stack around array corrupted

Tags: c++, c, assembly

**Error:**

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted.
```

This seems to be a common error on this forum; however, I was unable to find one that had assembly code mixed into it. Basically, my program is to convert decimal to binary (16-bit representation). After completing the coding, everything seems to compute correctly and convert the decimal to binary without an issue; however, after the **"Press any key to continue . . ."**, the error above pops up.

I do not believe the C++ code is causing the issue as it is very basic, and is there only to invoke the assembly function.

Again, the computation is correct as the program will produce the correct conversion (i.e: Decimal = 10, Binary Conversion: 0000000000001010), but just giving me the error at the end of the program.

**C++ Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern"C" void decToBin(char[], int, int);

int main()
{
//Initialize array and variables
const int SIZE = 16;
char arr[SIZE] = { NULL };
int dec = 0;

//Ask user for integer that they want to convert
cout << "Please enter integer you want to convert to binary: ";
cin >> dec;

//Assembly function to convert integer
decToBin(arr, dec, SIZE);

cout << "The 16-bit binary representation of " << dec << " is: ";

//Display the 16-bit binary conversion
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cout << arr[i];

cout << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

**Assembly Code:**

```
.686
.model flat

.code

_decToBin PROC              ;Start of project

start:
push ebp
mov ebp,esp             ;Stack pointer to ebp

mov eax,[ebp+8]         ;Address of first array element
mov cx,[ebp+12]         ;Integer number being passed - Copying onto 16 bit register
mov edx,[ebp+16]        ;Size of array

loopme:                     ;Loop to fill in array
mov ebx,0               ;Initializes ebx to store carry flag after shift
cmp edx,0               ;Compare edx with 0 to see if we should continue
je alldone              

shl cx,1                ;Shift the value to the left
adc ebx,0               ;Check carry flag and add 1 if CF(CY) is set to 1 and stay at 0 if CF(CY) is 0
add ebx,48              ;Since array is CHAR, adding 48 will give correct 0 or 1 instead of null

mov [eax],ebx           ;Copy the 0's or 1's into the array location

dec edx                 ;Decrement the counter
inc eax                 ;Move the array up an index

jmp loopme

alldone:    
pop ebp
ret

_decToBin ENDP

END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no assembler to compile your code, but you write 32-bit values into a `char[]` at this line:

```
mov [eax],ebx           ;Copy the 0's or 1's into the array location
```

So, the last write will update the memory locations `arr[SIZE-1]` to `arr[SIZE+2]`.

Comment: Good catch.  It should be `bl` instead of `ebx`.

Comment: Whammm-o!!! Thank you so much. Since I am still new, it is a bit difficult remember the size of each register. To be clear, bl is 8 bit, bx is 16 bit, and ebx is 32 bit? Is every char[] index 8 bit worth of data? Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, the registers have these width. The size of one char is 8-bit.

Comment: @MartinZabel Understood. Thanks again for the clarifications. Cheers!